# Not able to read emoji in spark while reading from oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, ojdbc

I'm trying to perform a read in spark from oracle

```
    String drivingQuery = "(SELECT ID,MESSAGE FROM ALL_MESSAGES WHERE ID IN (100,101,102,103))TBL";
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    Dataset<Row> resultDf = spark
            .read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", drivingUrl)
            .option("dbtable", drivingQuery)
            .option("driver",driver)
            .load();

    resultDf.show(200,false);
```

However, this gives a weird output with some weird characters

```
+----------------------------+-------+
|ID                          |MESSAGE|
+----------------------------+-------+
|100.0000000000              |����   |
|101.0000000000              |����   |
|102.0000000000              |����   |
|103.0000000000              |����   |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

I tried various methods like using the encoding option in spark read. However, that didn't work as well. The only solution I have is to base64 encode in oracle db while reading

`String query = "select ID,utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(MESSAGE)) AS ENCODED_MESSAGE from ALL_MESSAGES WHERE ID IN (100,101,102,103)";`

This gives the expected output

```
+-----------------+-------+
|TO_CHAR(ID)      |MESSAGE|
+-----------------+-------+
|100              |     |
|101              |     |
|102              |     |
|103              |     |
+-----------------+-------+
```

I have the following dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the database has
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16 and
NLS_CHARACTERSET= UTF8

I want to know if there is any alternate way to read without doing the encode-decode part as we have this code in multiple places and replacing everything would take long time.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Oracle the client receives data in databases "native" encoding, which it most likely AL32UTF8 and it is up to client to convert it into Java's native encoding UTF-16.

There is also Oracle internal function `dump()` which will return internal representation of string(VARCHAR2) inside database.

If JDBC drivers fail to convert UTF8 into UTF16 properly it is possible that you found a bug in JDBC drivers.

Comment: I checked the database has NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16 and NLS_CHARACTERSET= UTF8, so if I'm correct the encoding is AL16UTF16 and that's being converted to Java's UTF-16?

Comment: It depends in datatype of your column. I assume it is VARCHAR2 but it also could be NVARCHAR2

Comment: The datatype is VARCHAR2